# PostgreSQL: How to insert multiple values without multiple selects?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have the problem that I need to insert into a table with 2 entries, where one value is constant but fetched from another table, and the other one is the actual content that changes.

Currently I have something like

```
INSERT INTO table (id, content) VALUES 
  ((SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = 'Smith'), 1),
  ((SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = 'Smith'), 2),
  ((SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name = 'Smith'), 5),
  ...
```

As this is super ugly, how can I do the above in Postgres without the constant SELECT repetition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
insert into table (id, content)
select id, unnest(array[1, 2, 5]) from customers where name = 'Smith';
```

Comment: The answer from a_horse_with_no_name is also valuable but this one is closer to the actual question. I wish I could accept two answers. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can cross join the result of the select with your values:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, content) 
select c.id, d.nr 
from (
  select id 
  from customers 
  where name = 'Smith'
) as c 
  cross join (values (1), (2), (5) ) as d (nr);
```

This assumes that the name is unique (but so does your original solution).

Comment: Just for fun: `select id, unnest(array[1, 2, 5]) from customers where name = 'Smith'`

Comment: You should make that into an answer Abelisto.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE
id customers.id%TYPE; 
BEGIN
select c.id into id FROM customers c WHERE name = 'Smith';
INSERT INTO table (id, content) VALUES 
(id, 1),
(id, 2),
....
END;
```